# invoke the Other menu on an ICS phone?

Tags: java, android, menu

What is a reasonable way to invoke the 'Other'(?) menu item in an ICS menu bar on a Galaxy Nexus?

I want to tap on the other menu (one with the three vertically stacked dots) to expose the menu items beneath it. I have been scanning the Android documentation having to do with menus, but nothing has leapt out at me yet.

TIA for any and all assistance!

Regards,

Steve O'Sullivan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do it would be to call `showOverflowMenu` if on the the main thread or `postShowOverflowMenu` if in a background thread.  Unfortunately, the class `com.android.internal.widget.AbsActionBarView` nor its concrete subclass `com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView`  which contain those methods are not exposed publicly.

Comment: Louie, is it possible to use this method directly? Cannot wait to try this! Thanks!

Comment: You could if you can either find the ActionBarView in your view hierarchy.  You could try doing `(ActionBarView) findViewById(com.android.internal.R.id.action_bar);` You could also try using reflection to access the `mActionView` instance variable of `ActionBarImpl`, which is a concrete subclass of `ActionBar`.  Beware however that using undocumented APIs like this will likely break in future SDK releases.